# Customtype array insert crash in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to insert an element in a custom type array. But I am getting out of index error. Below is my code:

```
var newCGList = [TTCareGiverItem]()
if let snapshotItems = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
   for (_, snapshotData) in snapshotItems {
       let dict = snapshotData as? NSDictionary
       if let cgList = dict?.value(forKey: "ul") as? NSDictionary {
          for cg in cgList{
              let cgKey = cg.key as! String
              for ctr in 0 ..< self.careGiverList.count{
              let key = self.careGiverList[ctr].id as String
              if key == cgKey{
                 let order: Int = Int(cg.value as! String)!
                 let aCG = self.careGiverList[ctr]
                 aCG.order = order
                 newCGList.insert(aCG, at: ctr)
                 break
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

What I am missing?

Comment: What you need to use is `append(_:)` not `insert(_:at)`

Comment: I need to insert in an order list append won't work.

Comment: @TechBee Why you use insert instead append?

Comment: Need an ordered list. Can't use append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newCGList` is empty at the time you try to insert the element. 
Not sure why you are using '`newCGList.insert(aCG, at: ctr)`', instead you can use'`newCGList.append(aCG)`'.

Comment: I need to insert in an order list append won't work.

Comment: Use append for first element, then try to insert by making sure that you are not inserting to an outer index.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your items to be at a certain index but the size of the list is smaller than the largest index that is needed then of course this is not possible and you will get that error (for e.g. in your case i'm guessing what's happening is only sometimes the elements get added to the list, so because of this the index you're trying to insert at for the next element will be larger than the size of the list, therefore, causing that error. In this case you should just use a dictionary that goes from int to your item). Otherwise, if all that matters is that they are in order then what you can do is check to see if the size of the list is less than which index you're trying to insert the item at. If it is, then just append it to the end